# Keep brightness high whilst multiplexing [SOLVED]

Tags: arduino, led, multiplexer, brightness

[image]I have searched a little but I'm a noob to electronics so it was hard for me to understand. So here is my problem. I have made a little 3 x 3 led matrix to test. When powering 1 led it was fine, but when I tried 3 at once, they were all dim. Should I be using a 100 ohm resistor instead of 220? Please give a simple and detailed response. Like I said, I'm new to all of this. (keep in mind this is just a test. I wouldnt actually use multiplexing to power 9 leds.)

Comment: Hi keearix, please remove *solved* from the title, just accept the answer to indicate it's solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a schematic. 3 x 3 LEDs is 9 LEDs.

If you are running the LEDs at 33% duty cycle (3 of 9 at once) then you need to pass 3x the current for the same brightness as DC (approximately).

So if 220 ohms looks okay to you, then more like 68 ohms (the LED forward voltage will rise a bit). That may be enough to damage the LED if the multiplexing stops.

That means that the LED is actually a bit less efficient if you are multiplexing it. The reason to multiplex is to reduce the number of drivers and port pins. If you want to be able to run 9 LEDs at 15mA average current then you need 130mA total. There is no free lunch.

Comment: +1 For "There is no free lunch". So so true at every turn.

Comment: Just added a schematic.

Comment: @keearix - that is **not** a schematic. It's a wiring diagram. In a schematic, components are laid out according to their role in the circuit, with power at the top, ground at the bottom, and data and control flowing, when possible, from left to right. No breadboards; no blue-green blobs; short, direct connections between components.

Answer (score 1):

I put in a small delay between code chunks. I also used 2 100 ohm resistors parallel for each column, so I got REALLY bright lights. (Don't do this unless you plan on having every light on at same time. If you run a LED through a 50 ohm resistance, you will wreck the LED and potentially also wreck the Arduino too. Be very careful when experimenting with low resistance, it can really benefit you, or it could cost you like 100 bucks. Basically what the guy who answered this said.)